# Indexing a 3D array along 1 axis using a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, numpy-ndarray

Say that I have a numpy array **a** with the shape: [*z, y, x*], and another array **b** with the shape: [*y, x*].

Array **b** contains indices along z that I would like to extract from **a** for each *y* and *x*.

So far I have the following inelegant way of doing this:

```
 from_a = np.full_like(b, np.nan)

 for i in range(y):
  for j in range(x): 

   des_ind = b[i,j]

   from_a[i,j] = a[des_ind,i,j]
```

Is there a nice neat pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Have you looked at fancy indexing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the array `b` directly as index for `a`:

```py
import numpy as np
z, y, x = 3, 4, 5
a = np.random.randint(10, (z, y, x))
# array([[[2, 1, 8, 3, 0],  | [[9, 3, 6, 8, 7],  | [[6, 6, 2, 1, 4],
#         [4, 0, 1, 2, 9],  |  [5, 9, 0, 7, 1],  |  [3, 9, 4, 4, 8],
#         [0, 0, 7, 2, 6],  |  [7, 9, 8, 4, 9],  |  [9, 7, 0, 3, 0],
#         [3, 5, 2, 9, 3]], |  [6, 8, 9, 5, 9]], |  [4, 3, 0, 1, 1]]])

b = np.random.randint(z, size=(y, x))
# array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 2],
#        [1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
#        [2, 0, 0, 0, 2],
#        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]])

from_a = a[b, 
           np.arange(y)[:, np.newaxis], 
           np.arange(x)[np.newaxis, :]]
# array([[9, 3, 6, 3, 4],
#        [5, 9, 0, 7, 8],
#        [9, 0, 7, 2, 0],
#        [3, 5, 9, 9, 3]])
```

See also [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)  for numpy arrays.